# Entity Framework Core and MySQL error with datetime values after scaffolding

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework Core 2.1, with the latest MySQL Entity Framework Core Data Provider version 8.0.18. MySQL version is 8.0.18 as well. I scaffold-ed the database and it created the models. Connecting and grabbing data works fantastic, no problems, until it gets to the datetime values.

In the database the columns data type is "DATETIME". In the model, they are DateTime?. In the database context .cs file the only setting that is set on these columns is the default value.

In Visual Studio (2019 16.4.0) when I grab an entity row, i get all the values for every column except the datetime columns, visual studio says: "Cannot provide the value: host value not found."

Values are there, i can see them, if i use direct SQL i can grab the data. Could it be that mysql provider is 100% useless with bugs, as it has been in the past?

Comment: Looks like VS issue. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/802367/datetimenow-cannot-provide-the-value-host-value-no.html

Comment: Holly cow how did you find that I was looking for like the last two hours. I searched everywhere...except of course there :) Thank you!!!

Comment: Just googled it

Comment: "Could it be that mysql provider is 100% useless with bugs, as it has been in the past?" This is still true. For EF Core, I personally recommend switching to https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql which already has support for 3.0 and is based on a better underlying ADO.NET library: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector .

Comment: I will definetly give it a try, I am waiting till they have 3.1 support (RC right now), because we still use .NET Framework 4.8, and it seems EF Core 3.1 backtracked to .NET Standard 2.0 instead of 2.1 as in 3.0. So that is great news for us, since we are on 2.1.

Comment: Also mentioned here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/786837/debug-in-visual-basic.html

Comment: Fixed in 16.4.3.